# How to produce .wasm file using emmake

Tags: makefile, cmake, sdl-2, emscripten, webassembly

I have this project skeleton on [github](https://github.com/Deathangel908/djangochat/tree/master/screen_cast_extension/mouse_move) The project allows to move a cursor using SDL lib. Which I want to port afterward into browser. The files were generated based on this [turorial](http://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2014/03/06/lesson-0-cmake)

**MouseMove/src/main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int, char**){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
            "Mouse coordinates test", 0, 0, 100, 100,
            NULL);
    usleep(1000);
    SDL_WarpMouseInWindow(window , 600, 600);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

**MouseMove/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
project(MouseMove)
add_executable(MouseMove src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MouseMove ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
install(TARGETS MouseMove RUNTIME DESTINATION ${BIN_DIR})
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(webassembly_plugin)

# Use our modified FindSDL2* modules
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${webassembly_plugin_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
# Set an output directory for our binaries
set(BIN_DIR ${webassembly_plugin_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# Bump up warning levels appropriately for clang, gcc & msvc
# Also set debug/optimization flags depending on the build type. IDE users choose this when
# selecting the build mode in their IDE
if (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "GNU" OR ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "Clang")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O2")
elseif (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "MSVC")
    if (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS MATCHES "/W[0-4]")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "/W[0-4]" "/W4" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4")
    endif()
endif()

# Look up SDL2 and add the include directory to our include path
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Look in the Lesson0 subdirectory to find its CMakeLists.txt so we can build the executable
add_subdirectory(MouseMove)
```

**[cmake/FindSDL2.cmake](https://github.com/Twinklebear/TwinklebearDev-Lessons/blob/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake)**

I can compile it into an executable file using emake

- `mkdir build && cd build`
- `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../`
- `emconfigure cmake .`
- `emmake make`

This will generate elf executable that I'm able to run on my x86 system and it indeed moves the mouse. How do I produce wasm file that's suitable for WebAssembly stack-based virtual machine? I need to execute this with `emcc` somehow so it accepts cmake configuration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be using `emcmake` instead of `cmake` + `emconfigure` + `emmake`. Not that I know this would be a source of problems, but I think it _could_ be, and I can't see any reason not to do it via `emcmake`, which is the documented approach. I don't think the approach you're using is documented anywhere. Correct me if I'm wrong.